# Highcharts polar : series appear over others when toggle to visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts, underscore.js

I'm using Highcharts to do a polar graph. When I load the page, some series aren't visible by default. The problem is when I want to show them, they appear above the others...

You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/kd2fs3rz/

The variable `data` is normaly load by Ajax when loading the page.

How can I do to have for exemple series 2 and 3 under serie 4 when I show them ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @yozh How can I do to have for exemple series 2 and 3 under serie 4 when I show them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the [zIndex](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.zIndex) of each series:

```
var zIdx = 0; // Within the function, but outside of the while loop

chart.addSeries({ 
    id: e.vag_id, 
    name: e.vag_id, 
    data: temp, 
    visible: visible, 
    zIndex: zIdx++ // Here
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd2fs3rz/2/)